# Vue component check if a vuex store state property is already filled with data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

here is my setup. The state "categories" in the state is fetched async from a json endpoint.

In the component I want to work with this data, but if I reload the page the categories are always empty.

```
methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            console.log(this.filter);
        },
        formCats(items) {
            console.log(items);
            // const arr = flatten(data);
            // console.log(arr);
        }
    },
    created() {
        const data = this.categories;

        this.formCats(data);
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['categories'])
    }
```

I also tried async created() with await this.categories. Also not working as expected! Would be great if someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the async fetch doesn't finish until after the component is already loaded.  There are multiple ways to handle this, here's one.  Remove `created` and turn `formCats` method into a `computed`.

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState(['categories']),
  formCats() {
    let formCats = [];
    if (this.categories && this.categories.length) {
      formCats = flatten(this.categories);
    }
    return formCats;
  }
}
```

`formCats` will be an empty array at first, and then it will immediately become your formatted categories when `this.categories` is finished fetching.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks, in the meanwhile I also found a solution to watch for it (also working). Is there a recommendation which ist the better solution and why? I am relative new to vue, so I am grateful for every tip.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome.  That's an option, and a third option would be responding to the resolved async promise.  I like `watch` the least of the options because it's more generic and more likely to reinforce less clear reactivity patterns.  But it works fine.  The [Vue guide on watchers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) says "computed properties are more appropriate in most cases" but concedes that watches may be needed (it's not needed here but you could use whichever you like more).